# AWS S3: confusion on bucket region and identityPoolId (Swift)

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble downloading a file from my AWS S3 bucket (Swift/iOS app).  It seems to be one of two problems, but I can't tell which:

1. Problem with my identityPoolId
2. Problem with the region for the bucket

If I create the credentialsProvider like this:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"];
```

I get the following error:

```
[Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=ResourceNotFoundException, message=Identity 'us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' not found.}]
```

I noticed the mismatch on the line where I create the credentials provider: the regionType is AWSRegionUSEast1, but I have "us-west-2" as part of the identityPoolId.

If I change the regionType to AWSRegionUSWest2 (to match my id), the ResourceNotFoundExeception goes away. But then I get this:

```
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Bucket>sportsmanregs</Bucket><Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><RequestId>AEFD833FF4E7B6F1</RequestId><HostId>mYxbBKlzTeWgVZW4W060+ESiBhWuxmfDDFE6UriXG7bqxA5NWuRbH9lu4NuGCaU/7H8f1hjAukA=</HostId></Error>
```

What is interesting is the above error is found in the data object in the completion handler, as in "data" in the following:

```
completionHandler = {
        (task, location, data, error) -> Void in DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
```

So the completionHandler gets called OK.  In the S3 console, the url to the file I am trying to download starts with "https://s3.amazonaws.com//xxx/xxx.tiff".  Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like both your identity pool and your S3 bucket are in the us-west-2 region. You addressed the identity pool part on yourself, and that is correct. In order to fix the bucket region on your code, you need to pass the region to the S3 call too, otherwise it will use the default of us-east-1 and give you that error.

An alternative would be to specify your url with [bucketname].s3.amazonaws.com, some people seemed to have success with that, but it will probably by just fixing the region.

Comment: When you say "pass the region to the S3 call", which call do you mean?  I'm using AWSS3TransferUtility.downloadData, but I'm not seeing a region parameter to that.

Comment: I noticed (in Amazon S3 console) it says my bucket has a region of "US Standard".  From what I have read, that means the East 1 region.  So I created another identity pool ID for the East 1 region, and use that in the call to create the credentials provider.
    `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"];`
So the regions should all match.

Comment: Now I am getting a different error:
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>1149B0237A37D778</RequestId><HostId>EYni7fxxxx=</HostId></Error>

Comment: Now it sounds like you just need to adjust the permissions your Cognito role have on the new bucket and you should be good to go.

Comment: OK, thank you.  I'm still trying to understand Cognito better.  Users of our app do not login; we just want the app to be able to download a few files from S3 on startup.  So how does that type of authentication work?  When creating the identity pool, I have checked the box "Enable access to unauthenticated identities".
Do I also need to use a AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper as described here?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Comment: Yes! When you do that, you're going to specify your identity pool ID and region, and that class is what is going to retrieve AWS credentials (representing your unauthenticated role, since you are not passing in any login information). Those credentials are necessary to access S3.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this.  Let me know if you are still OK answering questions, or if I should start a new thread.  The issue is with the call to getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity, specifically about how to create the logins parameter.  I'm following the instructions in the link above (developer guide), which have the following example (Swift):
//from backend call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with logins map containing "your.provider.name":"enduser.username"
I know what the provider name is, but I don't know about enduser.username.

Comment: We don't have any backend process that validates users.  The users of our app don't login.  I'm also struggling understanding this part of the documentation (again from the link above):
"You obtain a token by calling GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. This API must be invoked from your backend using AWS developer credentials. It must not be invoked from the client SDK."

Comment: Where do I get "AWS developer credentials"?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question since this is diverging a little bit, but here's my understanding: if you don't have customers logging in, you should actually be using an unauthenticated role, rather than developer authenticated identities. Developer authenticated identities is an alternative to Google, Facebook, Amazon, etc. This means your users would still have to login, but the Identity authority would be something you built, instead of Google, etc. I think if you switch to unauthenticated identities, you'll get what you need.

Comment: I created a chat room if you want to talk more: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138872/cognito-identity-q-42866489

Comment: Just got it working!  In my IAM Role, I recreated the role policy, using the instructions here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html
I think the first time I did not correctly enter the ARN for our bucket, under the policy permissions.  (I think the first time I put the ARN for the identity pool or something like that).
I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score -2):

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-west-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"];
```

It is correct but you need to add some line of code. Please add this code:

```
 NSString *cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId;
    NSString *cognitopoolId = credentialsProvider.identityPoolId;
    NSLog(@"This is cognitoId: %@",cognitoId);
    NSLog(@"This is cognitopoolId: %@",cognitopoolId);

    [[credentialsProvider getIdentityId] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task){

        if (task.error == nil) {
            NSString* cognitoId = credentialsProvider.identityId;
            NSLog(@"cognitoId: %@", cognitoId);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error : %@", task.error);
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

Comment: Code it self is not the answer. You should answer question: Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem is here?